# Rest API UPDATE/DELETE - check if resource exists or not?

Tags: api, rest

This is basically *best practice* question. In my Rest API (that I am currently working on) I have routes matching `PUT` and `DELETE` requests on URLs like `/resources/{resourceID}`. Behind the API lies SQL DB.

In general, executing a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` query on non-existing resource ID in SQL databases gives no error, only the `affectedRows` returns 0.

Now I have a question on how to perform such request properly:

1. check if the resource with given ID exists prior to `UPDATE` or `DELETE` (which involves additional SQL query)
2. trigger the `UPDATE` / `DELETE` query without checking for existence and inspect the result of SQL query and return `HTTP 404` in case when `affectedRows == 0`?

I personally prefer the later one. But I can think of other DBMS (not SQL or not relational) where performing `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` queries may not return any information about affected rows. How to proceed in such cases?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are performing `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations using the resource ID, I cannot see any problems on checking the number of affected rows. This should be enough to check whether your resource exists or not.

Basically:

- For databases which the affected rows can be checked, just perform a `DELETE` or an `UPDATE`.
- For databases which this feature is not available, perform a query first.

Comment: See my answer do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

As a user of your API I would expect to get a `HTTP 404` for a non-existent resource independent of the used HTTP method.

Me trying to delete `/users/ted` when I really wanted to delete `/users/tod` could be a huge problem. Without `404` I would assume everything worked fine and the user I wanted to delete was in fact deleted. When in reality I deleted a non-existing user.

Comment: This is obvious. I am more interested in considering whether to do extra query to find out if the resource exists or rely on the result from DB engine after DELETE / UPDATE on non-existent resource... And how to handle this in case the DB engine does not provide any useful result in this case...

Comment: So your question isn't about the tags api or rest but more database related. As others have pointed out you should try to use the possibilities of your database as much as possible. If not supported first try to select the row before deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

In the update service I'd return `201 (CREATED)` in case the resource isn't there and you want your services to be 'tolerant', otherwise return `404` if you want your clients to strictly adhere to your protocol. 
In case of delete, You could return `404` if the client tries to delete a non existing resource, or if you keep track of deleted resources (some services do it, they just flag 'deleted' a resource, e.g. in order to give clients the chance to undo the operation) you could return `409 (CONFLICT)` to tell the client that the resource is already deleted.
In case of DBMS that don't give a clue about affected rows, you could query the resource prior to executing the action (be it insert, update or delete). It's a bit of an overkill, but if that's the only way to know about the state of the resource prior to acting on it and you don't expect performance problems, it may be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't prefer to check the number of affected row for updating records cause if the updated values are same as previous values then the number of affected row will be 0 which will result to 404 http status and that is not actually what happened.
I don't know either the solution 1 is perfect. But it seems to work in this case.